# Ipython interact function plots multiple plots instead of editing the one

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter v1.00,Ipython v6.0 and conda v4.3.16 for creating interactive plots. I'm using the following code which is supposed to create one plot and editing it after the change, but it creates multiple plots every time the *power* variable is changed. why it behaves like this? is it a new thing in Ipython 6.0? I can confirm that it is working in Ipython v5.0

```
%matplotlib inline
from ipywidgets import interact, IntSlider
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

power_slider = IntSlider(min=1, max=5)
@interact(power=power_slider)
def plot(power):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    plt.plot(np.power(range(10), power))
    return plt
```

[image]

Comment: try returning the figure, not the `pyplot` module

Comment: still, drawing multiple plots

Comment: I have the same problem. Unfortunately, I could not yet find a solution. Are you using macOS?

Comment: Nope, I'm in Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
%matplotlib notebook

from ipywidgets import interact, IntSlider
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

power_slider = IntSlider(min=1, max=5)
@interact(power=power_slider)
def plot(power):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    plt.plot(np.power(range(10), power))
    return plt
```

[image]